# How can I compare two columns of the table and display third output?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
top nd
1   0
0   1
0   1
1   0
```

I have a table tbl_data with structure like above. If top is "1" then I have to show "T" and if nd id "1" then I have to show "N".

Seriously, I dont know how to write query to compare above result. 
I tried using select (case when top ='1') but I am lost.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If `top` is 1 and `nd` is 1 do you have to show `TN` or is that not a valid combination?

Comment: @Nick top and ND can not be 1 but if that case occur then it should be T

Comment: What output do you want if neither `top` nor `nd` is 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a `CASE` expression to get your desired result. Since we check for `top = 1` first, if both `top = 1` and `nd = 1` then you will get the desired result of `T`:

```
SELECT top, nd, 
       CASE WHEN top = 1 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN nd = 1 THEN 'N'
       END AS topnd
FROM table1
```

Output:

```
top     nd  topnd
1       0   T
0       1   N
0       1   N
1       1   T
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7fa9ff8de291f42c76a3108cf84fecb4)

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why you lost.it can be done with simple case statement.

```
SELECT top, nd, 
       CASE WHEN top = 1 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN nd = 1 THEN 'N'
       END AS topnd
FROM TableName
```